# How to recover exactly one deleted file using hg

Tags: mercurial

Recently I was working in the local copy of my repository and accidentally deleted a file. I had made various edits since my last `hg commit` and didn't know what to do. In the end I went to the bitbucket.org website, found the file, clicked on `Open raw` and downloaded it through my browser. This worked but is clearly not the right thing to do.

If we call the file I deleted `file.txt` and the repo `code-repo`, how should I have recovered the deleted file using `hg`?

(My system is Ubuntu based.)

Comment: Did you just delete it using your computer's file system? Or did you delete it *in hg*?

Comment: Using "rm file.txt". I deleted it locally not in hg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you modified a source-controlled file, but before committing any of the modifications back to source control, the file was deleted.

**In this case you have to treat this like any other lost-file scenario, the fact that it was in source control doesn't seem to help at all** (*barring some exceptions listed below*). I would look into what capabilities your operating system / filesystem have for file recovery (such as "trash" or "recycle bin" folders, if any).

Caveats - you could be lucky and some kind of automatic backup or copy of the file might exist with at least some of your changes. I would look for:

- *.bak or *.orig files which could have been created by an editor or the source control tool
- The Mercurial 'shelf' if you ever use that feature
- The Tortoise HG 'shelf' if you ever use that feature (not the same as the standard Mercurial one actually)
- Double check the edited file isn't still open inside an editor. (This has saved me more than once!) Be careful if the editor says "this file has changed, do you want to reload" to click NO.
- Files in your temp folder which might happen to be autosaves from an editor. Look at the timestamps to see if any could be from the right time period.

---

Assuming you can't recover your edited file, you can at least get back to the latest version in hg pretty easily:

`$ hg revert path\to\filename`

This will bring back the file at its state in the changeset which was the parent of the working folder.

Comment: I think `hg revert` may be the answer. Thank you.